# Can I disable Activities in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu and one of the features I've never found a use for is Activities. For the uninitiated, it lets you set up your desktops and applications based on the activity you're doing... Pretty smart stuff if you need or want it, but I don't.

It currently litters several context menus in and around the desktop and while that isn't causing me physical harm, I'd prefer it if KDE just pretended Activities never existed.

Is there a way to disable Activities completely for a user (or globally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes. For now it is not very easily done by a user. The [KlyDE](http://blogs.kde.org/2013/04/11/hackweek9-lightweight-kde-desktop-project-updated) project is working on making this easier for any user. It will be able to be achieved, by either not installing the particular module of KDE, or by configuring settings.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to turn off activities. You are already using activities if you are using KDE Plasma. Your desktop, or virtual desktops, are an activity. By adding a new activity, you are creating another group of virtual desktops, just like the one you are now using. The global settings, like how many desktops there are in a group, carry over from one group to another. The technical details of what is allowed differs from distro to distro and, in my experience, Arch and Chakra have worked the best. openSUSE had all of the settings, but was somewhat unstable upon changing them. Some distros allow a different wallpaper on each desktop, and some do not. I did not like activities to begin with, as my previous comment will show. I urge you to play with them, because they really are useful. Like I said, you are already using them and just don't know it, but they can be removed from the panel if you insist. Trust me though, it is worth playing with them for a while. When you get used to it, you will be zooming around in an uncluttered environment in no time.

Answer (score 1):

The best I have been able to accomplish is removing them from the panel so that I don't get the notion to play with them anymore. I like the idea, but every time I try to set them up differently, I end up losing most or all of my settings from my original desktop. I'm sure it's my fault, but it should be harder to screw things up that badly. Just add more virtual desktops and avoid the frustration and loss of time. Maybe it will be better in Plasma 5! I do love the KDE experience, with this one small exception. Maybe some explicit directions on what to avoid could be offered in a popup during setup.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enought to disable global shortcuts as I use Meta+Q and Meta+S for other purposes:

- launch "Global (Keyboard) Shortcuts",
- navigate to "KWin" component,
- search for "activi"
- and disable 3 shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't disable activities but... What I've done is; using the shortcut setting I erased all the shortcut that are using activities the net effect of that is that you have only the default activity but is transparent because you cannot access to the activity bar or change to other activity so... it's disabled in practice